# Perfect reason for ban to ask more query?

Tags: discussion, support, specific-question, reputation, post-ban

Yesterday, I have asked a question [Difference between `Tracert` and `Traceroute`](https://superuser.com/questions/1124531/difference-between-tracert-and-traceroute) that was treading.

But, I am unable to ask more queries since "You have reached your question limit", before my above qury that message was not showing, that queries has positive score then why I got ban to ask more query?

> Can you explain it, please?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have asked a total of 14 questions on this site, of which only 6 have remained open or not been deleted. Many of your deleted questions were downvoted, ignored or otherwise off-topic

Your current question is of good quality, so may be helping you, but it is entirely possible that you have been rate limited by the automated quality ban system. We have no control of this ban system and it is imposed by the software underlying the Stack Exchange system

You should read and follow the advice on our help page [Why are questions no longer being accepted from my account?](https://superuser.com/help/question-bans)

You can choose to improve the questions that you yourself have deleted, or it may be that your recently well received question may be enough to allow you to post in the near future. Be aware though that any further downvotes or deletions may lengthen your ban. This is advice only and I do not know for certain how to reinstate your ability to ask questions.

Links to your deleted questions:

> https://superuser.com/questions/1015095/can-we-block-tcp-traffic-from-a-specific-user-on-a-multi-user-system-for-an-hour
>
> https://superuser.com/questions/1002661/performing-reverse-lookup-of-ip-address-to-its-hostname
>
> https://superuser.com/questions/999432/what-is-difference-between-disk-formating-and-flopy-disk-format
>
> https://superuser.com/questions/990668/what-im-missing-to-solve-time-period
>
> https://superuser.com/questions/982001/an-interaction-between-a-web-browser-and-a-web-server
>
> https://superuser.com/questions/971957/what-is-the-efficiency-of-a-stop-and-wait-protocol
>
> https://superuser.com/questions/968230/must-l1-be-write-through-cache
>
> https://superuser.com/questions/966825/application-layer-pdu-size-guaranteed-to-pass-without-fragmentation-on-to-the-t

Comment: Thanks for nice explanation.

Comment: I have deleted only 4 questions given link above where other are deleted my Moderator.  Should I undelete these 4 my questios and spend time to improve?

Comment: Apologies, I looked a a few of the latest and oldest and saw some deleted by yourself, so not all were deleted by you. I would consider if you can improve the questions before you undelete them as there would be no benefit if they only got deleted again. I do not know if posting answers might help you, but the help page specifically mentions that contributing positively to the site may help. At this point all I can say is to improve what you can, contribute as much as you are able to (lacking the ability to ask questions) and/or see if the ban lifts given some time.

Comment: @MithleshUpadhyay Deleted by you, a moderator, or the community the end result is the same.  You should have improved those existing questions instead of self-deleting them, and improved the community deleted questions, before asking additional questions